# Why doesn't this class return the JSON data from given URL?

Tags: android

The class that I have made does not fetch data from the given URL which I have as a String. In a static initializer I make a URL from the String, and then getResponseFromHttpUrl method should have returned the JSON data as a String. However my Log.d("jsondata") don't show anything at all and my app crashes.

```
package com.example.android.bakingapp;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecipeJson {
    public static final String url = "https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json";
    public static URL urlBuilt;
    public static String jsonData;

    static {
        try {
            urlBuilt = buildUrl();
            jsonData = getResponseFromHttpUrl(urlBuilt);
            Log.d("jsondata", jsonData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static URL buildUrl() throws java.net.MalformedURLException {
        return new URL(url);
    }

    public static String getResponseFromHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

            boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
            if (hasInput) {
                return scanner.next();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the app logs:

```
08-07 20:59:54.776 26319-26319/com.example.android.bakingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.bakingapp, PID: 26319
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.example.android.bakingapp.RecipeListFragment.onCreateView(RecipeListFragment.java:68)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3248)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1382)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:194)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:157)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:72)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
        at com.example.android.bakingapp.dummy.DummyContent.makeJsonArray(DummyContent.java:55)
        at com.example.android.bakingapp.dummy.DummyContent.<clinit>(DummyContent.java:28)
```

The culprit is this line:

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray(RecipeJson.jsonData);
```

Which means the problem is really with my class. But what is the source of the problem?

Edit: Here is the RecipeListFragment code

```
package com.example.android.bakingapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.android.bakingapp.dummy.DummyContent;
import com.example.android.bakingapp.dummy.DummyContent.DummyItem;

/**
 * A fragment representing a list of Items.
 * <p/>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link OnListFragmentInteractionListener}
 * interface.
 */
public class RecipeListFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    int dp;
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public RecipeListFragment() {
    }


    public static RecipeListFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        RecipeListFragment fragment = new RecipeListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        dp = config.smallestScreenWidthDp;
        if (dp < 600) mColumnCount = 1;
        else mColumnCount = 3;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipelist_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecipeListRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS, mListener));
        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {

        void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyItem item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the RecipeListFragment code? :)

Comment: API method call in static?

Comment: @egoldx Is that a problem?

Comment: @DivyanshuVarma Which Android Version you are using for testing?

Comment: Android P on an emulator.